# Reactivate my app from the status bar icon

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsstatusitem

I'm building a Mac app that has no dock icon, but a status bar icon, so the only way of bringing it is from the status icon.

When the app is active i can bring my NSWindow on screen from the status icon without problems. The problem appears when the app looses focus, at that point the app hides itself. I don't know how to make the app again active when i click the status icon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `NSApplication`'s [activateIgnoringOtherApps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html):?

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Comment: I'm new to AppKit, didn't knew about it. It works as expected, thank you!